# Any way to preprocess storage bus message before azure function and store headers to the execution context?

Tags: azure

I'm having service bus messages which contain some service information in their headers (for example some connection info). I also have the azure function, triggered by those messages. Connection info from the message header is used, f.e., inside some repository and and for more clear code I'm not passing it through the call stack but use AsyncLocal<> for storing it and accessing from any part of the code. The extraction of this connection info from the message header for now is placed at the start of each function.

Is it possible to move this headers extraction/preparation to somewhere else? Or a more common question - does azure functions pipeline has something like middleware?